# my flutter application, the output throw an error

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

my flutter out after running/launching it.

it's giving a `gradle` build problem:

```
BUILD FAILED in 2m 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            133.2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i tried `flutter doctor` and my output met requirements

Comment: Without more information, it will be impossible for anyone to help you. Please user ```flutter run --verbose``` to get more information about why your build is failing. Post the relevant output here if you still have questions.